# Looking for a "Neat" Transform to Yield a Convex Set

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, transformation

Optimizing on a unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$  is almost a convex problem (if the function is convex in the new set) if we make our "new" set $\mathbb{R}^n$, via the stereographic projection.  Clearly now the new set, $\mathbb{R}^n$,  is convex and optimizing here is equivalent to optimizing on the sphere (minus one point of course, which will be assumed to be a bad point, the point at infinity).  So all the grand theory of convex optimization may be applied.

Now suppose, instead, that your constrained space is the following:

Given a matrix $A \in M(n,n)$, there are $n$ constraints,

$\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j}^2=1$  for every $i\in \{ {1,\cdots, n}\}$

Is there a 'neat' way to turn this constrained set into a convex one, without losing much information much akin to the previous example.

We may think of this matrix $A$ as lying in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ where the representation is given by a vector $v=(A_{1,*},\cdots, A_{n,*})$; where $A_{i,*}$ is the $i$th row of $A%$.

Comment: One point perhaps worth pointing out is that each of the rows considered individually lies on the n-sphere  and so if we just had a single row we can make that source convex by aforementioned method. The point here is we have a (square) matrix and not sure what this space "looks" like. Maybe the matrix lies on some product space of the spaces defined by it's rows?